# ¿Cómo ejecuto un archivo ejecutable desde Javascript o NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, exe

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un archivo, pero lanza el siguiente error:

> child is not a function at Object../

Este es el código que encontré para ejecutar un archivo pero no funciona:

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile;

var executablePath = "C:\\Program Files 
(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
       console.error(err);
       return;
    }

    console.log('codigo',data.toString());
});
```

Comment: Resulta que estoy usando electronjs, es una aplicación de escritorio.

Comment: Si es con node.js

Answer (score 1):

Si es en **node.js**, prueba a cambiar la primera línea por:

```
var child = require('child_process').spawn;
```

No obstante, si lo que intentas es hacerlo desde el navegador, eso es del todo imposible.

Comment: Una cosa que note es que ivar no es una declaración de variable valida... corregire ese pequeño detalle de la linea 1.

Comment: @Riven entiendo que es un error a la hora de copiar el código, si no, el error sería distinto.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede por temas de seguridad, ningún navegador permite a una página web acceder a los recursos del sistema salvo en casos muy puntuales (el único caso que conozco es para elegir un fichero para subirlo usando un input de tipo file).

Comment: Ha indicado node.js. De lado servidor, JavaScript se usa en ndoe.js como backend y si puede ejecutar programas. No obstante, la pregunta es muy ambigua y me hace dudar el "JavaScript o Node.js", le he preguntado por ello por si las moscas.